# Add target=_blank to every link in a HTML string

Tags: javascript, html, dom, hyperlink

I have a string `s` (paragraph of text in HTML format) and I'm using this to include it in a `div`.

```
document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML = s;
```

`s` might contain a few `<a href="...">...</a>` links. **How to automatically add `target="_blank"` to these links?** (so that if the user clicks on them, it won't replace the current page)

I was thinking about using some kind of regex to detect links in `s`, detect if target=_blank is already present, and if not, add it, but this seems complicated.
Would it be better to add `target=_blank` after `s` is inserted in the DOM after `.innerHTML = s`? If so, how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After adding anchors with `innerHTML`, iterate through all the anchors with `querySelectorAll()`. Then set the `target` attribute with `setAttribute()` like the following:

```
document.querySelectorAll("#mydiv a").forEach(function(a){
  a.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
})
```

Answer (score 2):

> Would it be better to add target=_blank after s is inserted in the DOM
>   after .innerHTML = s? If so, how?

After doing the `innerHTML`

```
document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML = s;
```

Iterate all the link `a` inside `myDiv` and set this attribute `target` to them

```
var myDivEl = document.getElementById( "mydiv" ); //get the reference to myDiv element
var anchorsInMyDiv = myDivEl.querySelectorAll( "a" ); //get all the anchors in myDiv element
[ ...anchorsInMyDiv ].forEach( s => s.setAttribute( "target", "_blank" ) ); //iterate all the anchors and set the attribute
```